# "sticky" permissions upon folder/file creation

Tags: macos, permissions

I have a Mac mini running 10.6.8; I would like to configure several directory hierarchies such that whenever my wife or I create new files/directories in there that the other has read/write permission on that file/directory automatically (we both belong to the same group).

My first thought was, "just set the sticky bit on the parent directory", but then I realized that my definition of "sticky" was different from the system's.

Another thought was setting a 'umask' command in our respective .profile or .zshrc files, but then that effectively makes it a filesystem-global setting, which I'm not sure is really what I want to do.

Another suggestion was using ACLs, specifically something like:

```
chmod +a "MYGROUP allow list, add_file, search, add_subdirectory, delete_child, readattr, writeattr, readextattr, writeextattr, readsecurity, writesecurity, chown, file_inherit, directory_inherit" MYDIR
```

But I'm a little unsure of the exact attributes I'd want.

What say ye?  Is there a better way, or is one of these the "right" way?

Thanks!

randy

Comment: Sounds like an interesting question. I'm fairly adept at OSX and Unix in general, but I'm having a hard time following what your question is exactly. Maybe it's time for more coffee?

Comment: My question is: can I configure a parent directory such that when one user (me) creates a new file or directory, that new file or directory has read/write permissions automatically assigned to it such that another user (her) can also read/modify/delete said new file or directory.  As it stands now, I create a file/dir, but my wife (who is in the same group as me) only has read permissions; and vice versa: when she creates a new file/dir, I only have read permissions, not read/write.